# When using countdown timer i can only see the number 4 appearing in Flash as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a app in flash and i have a countdown timer. It starts at 60 seconds and goes down to zero but i can only see the number 4 appearing from numbers like 54, 44, 40, 34, 24, 14 and 4. I have tried this code separately on a another blank scene and it works but not on my app. 'myText_txt' is an instance name of dynamic text box. Help Please.

```
var count:Number = 60;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,count);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.start();
function countdown(event:TimerEvent):void {
myText_txt.text = String((count)-myTimer.currentCount);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, it could be you have not embedded all the numeral characters on the font assigned to myText_text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you embed the font?
If you don't, flash will only be able to show chars that are already contained in the TextField (i guess there is a "4" in it).

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts.html